# How to define left top of easyui panel

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui-layout, and it has two divs(west and center)

When loading the page, fdiv,cdiv and ftdiv should be colsed, and only first div displays in the center div. and it works successfully.

I have defined left:300px;top:300px of first div.But they does not work.

Here is js code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#fdiv').window('close');
      $('#cdiv').window('close');
      $('#ftdiv').window('close');
   });
</script>
```

Here is html code:

```
<div class="easyui-layout" style="width:100%;height:800px;position:absolute;top:95px;">
 <div id="p" data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="function" style="background:lightgrey;width:10%;padding:10px">
 ..................
 </div>

 <div data-options="region:'center',title:'content'">
     <div id="fdiv" class="easyui-panel" style="padding:5px;width:100%">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="$('#dlg').dialog('open')" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-newfile'"></a>
       <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-cancel'">delete</a>
       <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-print'">print</a>
       <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" data-options="plain:true,iconCls:'icon-search'">checkstat</a>  
     </div>
     <div id="cdiv" class="easyui-panel" title="" style="width:100%;height:708px;" data-options="footer:'#ft'">
       asdfsdf
     </div>
     <div id="ftdiv" style="padding:5px;"></div>

    <div class="easyui-panel" style="left:300px;top:300px;width:30%;height:30%" data-options="style:{borderWidth:2}">
       first div
    </div>
 </div>
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested:

```
<div class="easyui-panel"  data-options="style:{position:'absolute',borderWidth:2,width:40%,height:300px}">
       first div
    </div>
```

and

```
<div class="easyui-panel" style="left:600px;width:40%;height:300px;borderWidth:2" data-options="">
       first div
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, they both fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('#fstDiv').panel({   
    width:500,         
    height:150,        
    iconCls:'icon-edit',  
    left:600,           
    top:200,             
});
   $('#fstDiv').panel('panel').css('position','absolute'); 
 });
</script>
```

It works fail again